# ヘルプセンターの "保護された質問への回答" を改善したい

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターで権限に関する説明が記載された [保護された質問への回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) において、
おかしな点が二つあります。

"投稿にリンクを追加する方法は？" の箇所で

- "編集者" ツールバーボタンと訳されているが、実際には "エディタの" ツールバーボタン
- 同じくツールバーボタンの説明で画像に [image] が表示されるが、実際の表示 [image] と一致していない。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の通り、"エディタのツールバーボタン[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiCqc.png]"と変更されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]